# Where I can find an engine like OFPS Open Feedback Publishing

Tags: publishing, web-publishing

I'd like to write a little book on personal topics together with two friends of mine, remotely located. Do you know of any FOSS content publishing system  like the one from O'Reilly (OPFS)?

I saw the one that powers the [django book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/) but It seems that the code It's not released yet. I accept any kind of backend technology for this project.

I'd like to:

- edit the book on the web and let my friend do the same after authentication.
- anyone of us could comment other's entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I'm going to roll out my own solution following the direction written [**here**](http://toc.oreilly.com/2010/05/-wordpress-as-book-publishing.html). I like a lot thigs like [**bitesizeedits**](http://www.bitesizeedits.com) or [**leanpub**](http://leanpub.com/). The base will be a multiuser platform: [**mu**](http://mu.wordpress.org/). I'm quite fond with wordpress and as version control I'm happy with [**GIT**](http://git-scm.com/). The commenting system will be [**digress.it**](http://digress.it/).

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Google Wave](http://wave.google.com/about.html). You get the benefit of watching where others are editing / you can roll back the whole doc or specific parts / comment on specific parts plus you can use it from any computer so you don't have to be home or carry a laptop to edit your book when inspiration hits you.